# How to apply code to all the following rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code but it only work for my first row.
It is suppose to look if the checkbox on B, C or D is checked, and if so, a date + username will automaticaly fill in F and G.

here is a picture of my table:

[image]

This is what my code looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("B2") Or Range("C2") Or Range("D2") = True Then
Range("G2").Value = Environ("Username")
Range("F2").Value = Date
Else
Range("F2:G2").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what is it that you want to trigger the review/update of the row?  Typically you'd use the `Change` event for something like this, not `SelectionChange`

Comment: I have checkboxes as you see that are linked to the cells. When one of them is checked on a row , I want the column F that is on the same row (Date) to autofill with the timestamp and I want the column G that is also on the same row (ID) to give the Username() of the windows user... I don't know if I answered your question - I'm very new to VBA. Thank you!

Comment: You have hardcoded the ranges, so this would only work for row 2 as you've seen. 'Target' within the function is the calling cell from the selection change so you could use something like: Range("B" & Target.Row)

Comment: @Tragamor Yes I hardcoded the ranges. How do I make the code follow for the news rows? What about column G and F?  Range("G" & Target.Row) too? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this code in a regular module, select all your checkboxes and right-click >> assign macro then choose `ReviewRows`.

This will run the check whenever a checkbox is clicked - a bit of overhead since all rows will be checked, but should not be a big deal.

```vb
Sub ReviewRows()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 100 'for example
        With Sheet1.Rows(n)
            If Application.CountIf(.Cells(2).Resize(1, 3), "TRUE") > 0 Then
                If Len(.Cells(6).Value) = 0 Then 'only enter if currently empty?
                    .Cells(6) = Date
                    .Cells(7) = Environ("Username")
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(6).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
```

If you want to be more precise then `Application.Caller` will give you the name of the checkbox which was clicked, and you can use that to find the appropriate row to check via the `linkedCell`.

```vb
Sub ReviewRows()
    Dim n As Long, shp As CheckBox, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error in case calling object is not a checkbox
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller) 'get the clicked checkbox
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then          'got a checkbox ?
        If shp.LinkedCell <> "" Then    'does it have a linked cell ?
            With ws.Range(shp.LinkedCell).EntireRow
                If Application.CountIf(.Cells(2).Resize(1, 3), "TRUE") > 0 Then
                    If Len(.Cells(6).Value) = 0 Then 'only enter if currently empty?
                        .Cells(6) = Date
                        .Cells(7) = Environ("Username")
                    End If
                Else
                    .Cells(6).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
                End If
            End With
        End If 'has linked cell
    End If 'was a checkbox
End Sub
```

*However* this appraoch is sensitive to the exact positioning of your checkbox

Comment: It's working perfectly. The only tiny problem that i'm having is that every time i check a box, it adds the username + date (As expected), but the mouse cursor buffers for like 3 seconds and freezes excel at the same time. Is it because it itterate over 100 times ? (for n = 1 to 100). What can I do to fix that? My PC is kinda powerful, so having it freeze like that is scary.. I don't wanna see how it's gonna react in the work office! Thank you again!!

Comment: it's about 100 rows, but once i click in a checkbox, it should simply add the date+username on the same row, and then break out of the loop..!!

Comment: How did you add the checkboxes?  Do they all have unique names?

Comment: I added a checkbox for each cell, and connected every single checkbox to its respective cell using Format Control -> Cell link

Comment: See my update above - should work as long as your checkboxes all have a linked cell

Answer (score 0):

You have a long way to go!
Unfortunately, `If Range("B2") Or Range("C2") Or Range("D2") = True Then` is beyond repair. In fact, your entire concept is.

Start with the concept: Technically speaking, checkboxes aren't on the worksheet. They are on a layer that is superimposed over the worksheet. They don't cause a worksheet event, nor are they responding to worksheet events. The good thing is that they have their own.

`If Range("B2") Or Range("C2") Or Range("D2") = True Then` conflates `Range` with `Range.Value`. One is an object (the cell), the other one of the object's properties. So, to insert sense into your syntax it would have to read, like, If `Range("B2").Value = True Or Range("C2").Value = True Or Range("D2").Value = True Then`. However this won't work because the trigger is wrong. The Worksheet_Change event won't fire when when a checkbox changes a cell's value, and the SelectionChange event is far too common to let it run indiscriminately in the hope of sometimes being right (like the broken clock that shows the correct time twice a day).

The answer, therefore is to capture the checkbox's click event.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = vbTrue Then
        MsgBox "Clicked"
    End If
End Sub
```

Whatever you want to do when the checkbox is checked must be done where it now shows a MsgBox. You can also take action when it is being unchecked.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answers and explications. But, I would like to say... The checkboxes are linked to the cells under them. So if Check let's say B2 , then, B2 cell = True. Can't we do something with that? I didnt quite understook the Target.Adress code also... Sorry I'm very new to VBA. I usually only do web dev!

Comment: 999 apoligies! I posted the wrong procedure - now changed. The linked cell assumes the `Value` of the checkbox but the change triggers no event. Better drink directly from the well. The procedure runs when the checkbox named in its name is clicked. You get its `Value` at the same time as the linked cell.

Comment: But it still doesnt answer my initial question. I dont want to hard code every single checkbox, so this is why I linked them to a cell. Every checkbox is linked to its own cell. How to make every row follow the same code?

Comment: "Hard code" doesn't look like the correct word to me. But yes, you will need to write an event procedure for each checkbox. If you just want a time stamp, discard the check boxes and use the Worksheet_Change event to trigger the code. You would need to define what triggers the time stamp.